# How to config kannel gateway to receive messages from mobile phone?

Tags: kannel

I'm using Kannel as an SMS gateway to send and receive SMS messages. I have downloaded, installed, and configured Kannel according to the document guided. I can send an SMS by typing **http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&from=*"from number"*&to=*"to number"*&text=Testing** in a browser. However, when I send an SMS from a phone to the gateway, I got the error **ERROR: request failed**.

I'm using Kannel 1.4.3 installed on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I use a wavecom modem whose model is **WAVECOM FASTRACK** type **DUAL BRANCH MODEM** connected to kannel via serial port.

Should you need further information, please let me know.

I'm really thankful for your help.

**Kannel.conf**

> group = core
>
> admin-port = 13000
>
> admin-password = bar
>
> smsbox-port = 13001
>
> smsbox-port-ssl = false
>
> log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
>
> log-level = 0
>
> access-log = "/home/sambath/kannel/access.log"
>
> access-log-clean = true
>
> # SMSC GSM
>
> group = smsc
>
> smsc = at
>
> smsc-id = abc
>
> modemtype = wavecom
>
> device = /dev/ttyUSB0
>
> pin = 0000
>
> alt-charset = "ASCII"
>
> group = modems
>
> id = wavecom
>
> name = "wavecom"
>
> detect-string = "wavecom"
>
> message-storage = sm
>
> speed = 115200
>
> # SMSBOX SETUP
>
> group = smsbox
>
> bearerbox-host = localhost
>
> sendsms-port = 13013
>
> sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
>
> log-file = "/tmp/smsbox.log"
>
> #log-level = 0
>
> access-log = "/home/sambath/kannel/access.log"
>
> mo-recode = true
>
> # SEND-SMS USERS
>
> group = sendsms-user
>
> username = tester
>
> password = foobar

**access.log**

```
2010-10-04 14:36:30 Log begins

Receive SMS [SMSC:abc] [SVC:] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:] [from:+85516635262] [to:1234] [flags:-1:0:-1:0:-1] [msg:5:Hello] [udh:0:]

Sent SMS [SMSC:abc] [SVC:] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:] [from:1234] [to:+85516635262] [flags:-1:0:-1:-1:-1] [msg:14:Request Failed] [udh:0:]

2010-10-04 14:36:55 Log ends

Receive SMS [SMSC:abc] [SVC:] [ACT:] [BINF:] [FID:] [from:+85516635262] [to:1234] [flags:0:0:-1:0:-1] [msg:113:Your message on <04/10/10,14:36> has been received by +85516635262 on <04/10/10,14:36> Thank you for using hello.] [udh:0:]
```

**kannel.log**

```
2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/tmp/kannel.log' with level `0'.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: Started access logfile `/home/sambath/kannel/access.log'.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: SSL not supported, no SSL initialization done.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13000.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run)

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: starting smsbox connection module

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: BOXC: 'smsbox-max-pending' not set, using default (100).

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 4 (gw/bb_boxc.c:sms_to_smsboxes)

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/bb_boxc.c:sms_to_smsboxes) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 5 (gw/bb_boxc.c:smsboxc_run)

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/bb_boxc.c:smsboxc_run) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: Set SMS resend frequency to 60 seconds.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: SMS resend retry set to unlimited.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: smsbox MO concatenated message handling enabled

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <abc> disabled.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: AT2[abc]: configuration shows modemtype <wavecom>

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: Reading modem definitions from <kannel.conf>

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: Found <1> modems in config

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: AT2[abc]: read modem definition for <wavecom>

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 6 (gw/smsc/smsc_at.c:at2_device_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [6] DEBUG: Thread 6 (gw/smsc/smsc_at.c:at2_device_thread) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 7 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router)

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: trying to use speed <115200> from modem definition

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [7] DEBUG: Thread 7 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: ----------------------------------------

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: opening device

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [0] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: start called

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: device opened. Telnet mode = 0

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: device opened

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: speed set to 115200

2010-10-04 14:36:15 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> ^M

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT^M

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: Closing device

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: speed is 115200

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: opening device

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: device opened. Telnet mode = 0

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: device opened

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: Logging in

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: init device

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: speed set to 115200

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> ATZ^M

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:17 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT^M

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- AT

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT&F^M

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- AT&F

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> ATE0^M

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- ATE0

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+IFC=2,2^M

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CPIN?^M

2010-10-04 14:36:18 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- +CPIN: READY

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CMGF=0^M

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CSMS=?^M

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- +CSMS: (0,1)

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: Phase 2+ is supported

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CSMS=1^M

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- +CSMS: 1,1,1

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CNMI=1,2,0,1,0^M

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:29 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: AT SMSC successfully opened.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2524] [5] INFO: Client connected from <127.0.0.1> 

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2524] [5] DEBUG: Started thread 8 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2524] [8] DEBUG: Thread 8 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2524] [8] DEBUG: Started thread 9 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2524] [9] DEBUG: Thread 9 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender) maps to pid 2524.

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- +CMT: ,24

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- 07915815860000F0240B915815665362F200000101404163218205C8329BFD06

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: received message from SMSC: +85516800000

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: Numeric sender (international) <+85516635262>

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: User data length read as (5)

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: Udh decoding done len=5 udhi=0 udhlen=0 udh=''

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CNMA^M

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [9] DEBUG: send_msg: sending msg to box: <127.0.0.1>

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [9] DEBUG: boxc_sender: sent message to <127.0.0.1>

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [8] DEBUG: boxc_receiver: sms received

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [8] DEBUG: send_msg: sending msg to box: <127.0.0.1>

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [8] DEBUG: boxc_receiver: got ack

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:47 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: TP-Validity-Period: 24.0 hours

2010-10-04 14:36:47 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CMGS=27^M

2010-10-04 14:36:47 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- >

2010-10-04 14:36:47 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: send command status: 1

2010-10-04 14:36:47 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> 0011000B915815665362F20000A70ED272BC5E9ED341C6709A5D2603

2010-10-04 14:36:47 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> ^Z

2010-10-04 14:36:49 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- >

2010-10-04 14:36:49 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- +CMGS: 122

2010-10-04 14:36:49 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:36:49 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: send command status: 0

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2524] [8] DEBUG: boxc_receiver: heartbeat with load value 0 received

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2524] [8] INFO: Connection closed by the box <127.0.0.1>

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2524] [9] DEBUG: send_msg: sending msg to box: <127.0.0.1>

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2524] [9] DEBUG: Thread 9 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2524] [8] DEBUG: Thread 8 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- +CMT: ,118

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- 07915815860000F0040B915815665362F200100101404163328271D9775D0E6A97E7F3F0B90C7ABB413C18ED1583BD6230568CA69BD97C2074780E1297CB6E90BC3C2EA7ED6532489C07AD70B55ACC669BD5643619E8ED06F160B4570CF68AC158319A6E66F381A8E8B07B0DCABFEB20F35B0EAACFD3EE33085D66B3DF2E

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: received message from SMSC: +85516800000

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: Numeric sender (international) <+85516635262>

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: User data length read as (113)

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: Udh decoding done len=113 udhi=0 udhlen=0 udh=''

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] WARNING: smsbox_list empty!

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: --> AT+CNMA^M

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [4] WARNING: smsbox_list empty!

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [4] WARNING: smsbox_list empty!

2010-10-04 14:36:58 [2524] [6] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: <-- OK

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x957b368.

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [3] DEBUG: Shutting down Kannel...

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [3] DEBUG: shutting down smsc

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [3] DEBUG: AT2[abc]: Shutting down SMSCConn, slow

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [3] DEBUG: shutting down udp

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Resetting HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.

2010-10-04 14:37:02 [2524] [0] WARNING: Killing signal or HTTP admin command received, shutting down...

2010-10-04 14:37:03 [2524] [6] INFO: AT2[abc]: Closing device

2010-10-04 14:37:03 [2524] [6] DEBUG: Thread 6 (gw/smsc/smsc_at.c:at2_device_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [7] DEBUG: Thread 7 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/bb_boxc.c:sms_to_smsboxes) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/bb_boxc.c:smsboxc_run) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] INFO: All flow threads have died, killing core

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Waiting for 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) to terminate

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: No clients with requests, quitting.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x957b368.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] DEBUG: final clean-up for SMSCConn

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] DEBUG: smsbox MO concatenated message handling cleaned up

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] INFO: Total WDP messages: received 0, sent 0

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Remaining SMS: 1 incoming, 0 outgoing

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] INFO: Total SMS messages: received 2, sent 1

2010-10-04 14:37:12 [2524] [0] DEBUG: Immutable octet strings: 230.

**smsbox.log**

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/tmp/smsbox.log' with level `0'.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] INFO: Logging accesses to '/home/sambath/kannel/access.log'.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] INFO: Started access logfile `/home/sambath/kannel/access.log'.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13013.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 2535.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) maps to pid 2535.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] INFO: Set up send sms service at port 13013

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread) maps to pid 2535.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: ----------------------------------------------

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Kannel smsbox version 1.4.3 starting

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG:   dumping group (sendsms-user):

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG:     <group> = <sendsms-user>

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG:     <username> = <tester>

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG:     <password> = <foobar>

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 4 (gw/smsbox.c:obey_request_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/smsbox.c:obey_request_thread) maps to pid 2535.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 5 (gw/smsbox.c:url_result_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/smsbox.c:url_result_thread) maps to pid 2535.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 6 (gw/smsbox.c:http_queue_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [6] DEBUG: Thread 6 (gw/smsbox.c:http_queue_thread) maps to pid 2535.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] INFO: Connected to bearerbox at localhost port 13001.

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 7 (gw/heartbeat.c:heartbeat_thread)

2010-10-04 14:36:30 [2535] [7] DEBUG: Thread 7 (gw/heartbeat.c:heartbeat_thread) maps to pid 2535.

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2535] [4] WARNING: No translation found for <Hello> from <+85516635262> to <1234>

**2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2535] [4] ERROR: request failed**

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2535] [4] DEBUG: message length 14, sending 1 messages

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of 51b64a81-5f2a-488c-8cd8-9649b7cc9e0c

2010-10-04 14:36:46 [2535] [0] DEBUG: No client - multi-send or ACK to pull-reply

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [0] ERROR: SIGINT received, aborting program...

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [0] INFO: Received (and handled?) 1 requests in 9 seconds (0.11 per second)

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [0] INFO: Kannel smsbox terminating.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [7] DEBUG: Thread 7 (gw/heartbeat.c:heartbeat_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Waiting for 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) to terminate

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: No clients with requests, quitting.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Waiting for 4 (gw/smsbox.c:obey_request_thread) to terminate

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/smsbox.c:obey_request_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [6] DEBUG: Thread 6 (gw/smsbox.c:http_queue_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Waiting for 5 (gw/smsbox.c:url_result_thread) to terminate

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/smsbox.c:url_result_thread) terminates.

2010-10-04 14:36:55 [2535] [0] DEBUG: Immutable octet strings: 162.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think u may have missing SMS-service configurations

```
# Test
group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "This is a reply"
max-messages = 1
```